# ¿Qué debería devolver en una vista si la tabla que consulto no tiene registros?

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Estoy tratando de devolver los registros de una tabla en una vista (aplicación web ASP .NET MVC), si la tablas que consulto no tiene ningun registro , ¿Que debería devolver para no obtener la excepción de tipo System.ArgumentNullException?

Este es código de la consulta en la capa DAL:

```
public List<EmpleadoCLS> ObtenerEmpleados()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Agencia_MontanaEntities())
            {
                var listaEmpleados = (from empleado in db.Empleado
                                      join estado in db.Estado
                                      on empleado.FK_ID_Estado equals estado.ID
                                      join ciudad in db.Ciudad
                                      on empleado.FK_ID_Ciudad_Residencia equals ciudad.Codigo
                                      join genero in db.Genero
                                      on empleado.FK_ID_Genero equals genero.ID
                                      select new EmpleadoCLS
                                      {
                                          IdEmpleado = empleado.ID.ToString(),
                                          Nombre = empleado.Nombres,
                                          ApPaterno = empleado.Apellido_Paterno,
                                          ApMaterno = empleado.Apellido_Materno,
                                          IdTipoDocumento = empleado.FK_ID_Tipo_Documento,
                                          NumeroDocumento = empleado.Numero_Documento,
                                          Direccion = empleado.Direccion_Residencia,
                                          TelefonoFijo = empleado.Telefono_Fijo,
                                          TelefonoCelular = empleado.Telefono_Celular,
                                          Email = empleado.Email,
                                          FechaNacimiento = empleado.Fecha_Nacimiento,                                              
                                          NombreEstado = estado.Nombre,
                                          NombreCiudad = ciudad.Nombre,
                                          NombreGenero = genero.Nombre,
                                          FechaRegistro = empleado.Fecha_Registro
                                      }).ToList();
                if (listaEmpleados.Any())                    
                    return listaEmpleados;                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Este es el código en la capa BLL donde se genera la excepción:

```
public List<EmpleadoCLS> ObtenerEmpleados()
    {
        try
        {
            var listaEmpleados = empleadoDA.ObtenerEmpleados();
            if (listaEmpleados.Any())
                return listaEmpleados;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no debería tirar ninguna excepción en este caso. Una lista vacía es una respuesta perfectamente válida, algo sumamente común, no una excepción. Excepción es que la base de datos se desconecte en el momento que se está procesando la query. Excepción es que la query tome demasiado tiempo y te de un Timeout.

Con esto en mente, sólo has un return de `listaEmpleados`. Elimina ese `if (listaEmpleados.Any)` y vete sólo con el return.

```
 // en el BLL
 var listaEmpleados = empleadoDA.ObtenerEmpleados();
 return listaEmpleados;


 // en el DA
var listaEmpleados = (from c in ....
....
      }).ToList();
                          
return listaEmpleados;
```

Excepciones son exactamente eso. Excepciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probarlo.